# Passing Parcelable class with Serializable member not working

Tags: android, android-intent, serialization, parcelable

I'm trying to return result from activity. i have the following class:

```
@Parcelize
class UploadItem() : Parcelable {
   ... some more vars...
   lateinit var messageAttachment : MessageAttachment
}
```

Where MessageAttachment is a simple serializble class:

```
public static class MessageAttachment implements Serializable {
... some primitives...
}
```

So when i'm returning result in activity B:

```
    val resultIntent = Intent().apply {
        putExtra("TEXT", getComposerText())
        putParcelableArrayListExtra("ITEMS", completedItems)
    }

    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent)
    finish()
```

And getting the result from Activity A:

```
data.getParcelableArrayListExtra("ITEMS");
```

I'm getting an array with all items inside are ok except the SERIALIZABLE one.

Appreciate the help!